# Roundcube не работают уведомления о доставке и прочтении, куда смотреть?

Tags: настройка, roundcube

При отправке письма ставлю два чек-бокса

[image: Roundcube Webmail 1.4.3]

Но ни один не отрабатывает, уведомления не приходят, больше интересует "Уведомление о состоянии доставки", оно прям важно, куда смотреть, кто может подсказать?

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная проблема, автору +

Karmashkin @Karmashkin
это флаги в письме "о доставке" и "о прочтении" где то в настройках.
сейчас все почтовые клиенты не реагируют на эти флаги, т.е. тебе не будут приходить эти уведомления, если другая сторона специально не включила этот функционал.
https://qna.habr.com/q/348162

- Такое может быть?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).